# JNI: getting method id for private method in superclass

Tags: java, c, methods, java-native-interface

I am trying to call a private method from within the native implementation of another method like this:

```
jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
jmethodID output_mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "methodName", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
if (output_mid == 0)
{
    // Exit
}
```

This is giving me a "method not found" exception. From what I gather, the class object must correspond to the class where the target method was defined, because it is private.

Indeed if I change the access modifier to protected, the fault disappears. Also from the logs, I see GetObjectClass returned the runtime class, not the base class. So, my question is: how to get the correct base class, in JNI?

Comment: After your native code returns to Java, you should receive an exception.  Can you post the exception?

Comment: Not word for word, because I'd have to reintroduce the bug, which I am lazy to do, but I think it was an instance of MethodNotFoundException saying that 'methodName' does not exist. Thanks.

Comment: @PanayiotisKarabassis out of curiosity does the single change from private to protected fix your problem?

Comment: @jogabonito Yes it does.

Comment: @ChuckFricano It was a NoSuchMethodError.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a JNI function [`getSuperClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp18301) that you can use to obtain the correct class in this case. In the general case of knowing that a private method is defined in *some* superclass, you might need to walk the inheritance tree checking each superclass up to the root.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I suspected that, it's easier to change the modifier to protected. :-)

Comment: From the Java documentation.  "The JNI does not enforce class, field, and method access control restrictions that can be expressed at the Java programming language level through the use of modifiers such as private and final."  I don't see how adding protected or using getSuperClass() would fix this problem.

Comment: i agree with @ChuckFricano, that changing the visibility shouldn't help. But if it does work, who am I to say no :-)

Comment: @jogabonito, I tested this and the olny way to get the MethodNotFoundException was to to misspell the method name or signature.  It worked when the target Java method was in the base class, superclass, abstract superclass, private, public etc.

Comment: Perhaps you are right, the Exception may be thrown when the method is called. "When these functions are used to call private methods and constructors, the method ID must be derived from the real class of obj, not from one of its superclasses." Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html

Comment: Actually, it was a silly question in the first place. A private method is not visible in a child class, period. Silly me! But the calling code is also in the class where the private callee was defined, so if this were Java and not JNI, it would have worked.

Comment: @Panayiotis. For Java, your statement is true.  For JNI it is not ture.  I placed a private method in an abstract superclass and the JNI code found and invoked the method fine.  There was no java.lang.NoSuchMethodError exception.  I think your question is valid and provided me with an opportunity to try something like this.

Comment: Thanks, well I don't know, maybe we are using different versions of the Java virtual machine? I am programming for Android. I don't know how else to explain it. Regards.

Comment: From my experience this is unfortunately device specific. I have Samsung Galaxy S8 and Nexus 5X. The same code with private method in super class is crashing on Samsung (methodId == 0) but is working on Nexus... like wtf? Changing method to protected makes it work on both phones. (that's another wtf on it's own :D)

Comment: @bio007 The last one isn’t a WTF for sure, since that’s definitely the correct behavior. For the machine-dependence of the first issue, I’d say that’s a general weakness in the JNI spec. It’s not required that JNI is able to call a private method, but neither is it specifically called out as prohibited.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill sure if that would be in Java code it would make sense. But JNI is known for ignoring access modifiers and in this specific case it's honoring them? And only on some devices? Not really deterministic behavior.